# how to redirect a subdomain with child directory to new url using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a old website which used subdomains for each pages, i'm moving to new site and want to redirect the most of the links to the new pages.

I searched a lot but didn't find anything.

For instance i will be redirect this url to this:

blog.test.com/12/09/test-2 to test.com/blog/test-2
How it possible?
I tried this

or just simply redirect all the blog.test.com with whatever query they have to the new page?

blog.test.com/whatever?whatever to test.com/blog

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file of `test` subdomain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(blog)\.(test\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^\d{2}/\d{2}/(.+)$ http://%1/blog/$1 [L,R=302]
```

Comment: I don't have this subdomain any more, that's what i did is to point this subdomain to my new domain using CNAME

Comment: So `blog.test.com` is CNAME for `test.com`? This rule should still work for that case.